# Фильтр объектов по ManyToManyField

Tags: django

Всем привет!

В общем объясню ситуацию сначала:

У меня есть модель

```
class Friends(models.Model, MixinModel):
    by = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="from_friend")
    friend = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="to_friend")
    approve = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=RELATION_STATUS, default=State.No)
```

Она является промежуточной моделью для связи Profile и Profile. В внутри ListView профилей я переопределяю get_queryset (получается, это queryset профилей) по параметру approve промежуточной модели и текущему пользователю. Я ничего не придумал, кроме как отфильтровать по

f = Friends.object.filter(approve=State.No)

, получить из этого фильтра id-шники поля `by` и сравнить их с id-шниками дефолтного queryset-а.

Можно ли это сделать как-то более красиво и менее затратно?  Мне кажется должен быть путь фильтрации моделей по промежуточной модели. ведь незря ее придумали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете фильтровать через обратные отношения.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Если я правильно понял ваш случай, то как-то так:

friends = Profile.objects.filter(
    friends__approve=State.No,
)

Единственное, надо создать m2m связь (предполодим, назвав friends) на self в профиле и указать through таблицу.
Надеюсь поможет.

Если что, тут на эльфийском есть +- подходящий пример )
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891302/filtering-many-to-many-relationship-by-relationship-field-in-django

Comment: Спасибо, пример по ссылке у меня выдал `Cannot resolve keyword 'friends' into field`.Но каким-то чудом у меня заработало вот так: Profile.objects.filter(to_friend__approve=State.No)